# How to use node-module kappa?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I installed the node module kappa local on my machine in the directory `kappa-server` as described here: https://github.com/xjamundx/kappa/tree/patch-1#quickstart

my config.json looks:

```
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 8000
        }
    ],
    "plugins": {
        "kappa": {
            "paths": [
                "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If I curl the command for verifying: `http://localhost:8000/-/all`
it shows: 
`{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}`

in which directory must I put my own repositories now, and what is the command to clone a repository from my own local npm repository?
I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had to install a real npm repository first. Like reggie or npmjs.org